# How many symbols I can write in 1,2,4 bytes? asm

Tags: assembly, x86

I am studying asm, and I know that if I would like to take a number from keyboard, I can simple do this:

```
inputarea db 3 DUP(' '),'$'

mov ah,0Ah
mov dx,offset inputarea
int 21h
```

In this case, I can write symbols until I reach 255. But there is a db(*data byte*) type, so in this case I can only write max 3 numbers which is correct to asm to execute it (123 , 100 and so on...). But If have `Data Word`, or `DD` types, how many symbols I can write which can be executed?

Hint: for example, If I have type 'data byte', so this will exlude memory of 1 byte. And there is able to store only 3 numbers. What about others types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that if I would like to take a number from keyboard, I can simple do this:
>   ...

No, its not that simple - you have to setup a transfer buffer correctly. Function `0ah` reads from standard input and writes the characters it reads into a buffer, see [Interrupts MS-DOS Function Calls (INT 21h)](http://www.philadelphia.edu.jo/academics/qhamarsheh/uploads/Lecture%2021%20MS-DOS%20Function%20Calls%20_INT%2021h_.pdf), page 4:

```
count = 80
KEYBOARD STRUCT
    maxInput BYTE count      ; max chars to input
    inputCount BYTE ?        ; actual input count
    buffer BYTE count DUP(?) ; holds input chars
KEYBOARD ENDS

.data
inputarea KEYBOARD <>

.code
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, OFFSET inputarea
    int 21h
```

Then, you will end up with a string in the input buffer which you need to convert to a number.

Comment: another version I think is: inputarea db 3,?,3 DUP(' '). isn't it?

Comment: Yes, this should work also - the above structure basically expands to that